# Is there a way to change config options after compiling software?

Tags: php, compilation

I compiled php 5.4, and am trying to get an existing site ported to it.  The problem I'm seeing is that I didn't use the --with-pdo-pgsql option when running ./configure, so I can't connect to my db.

I've already compiled it twice, is there a way to update the configuration without rerunning make and make install?

Comment: Just wondering, is it really time consuming to recompile?

Comment: @Jared: Yea, at least an hour.  I let it run overnight both times, so I'm not 100% sure how long.  Also, I usually install from the repos, so I'm not super good at hand compiling, and I'm figuring this won't be my last time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the shared module was not built to begin with. I don't think PHP allows partial compile of modules, but check the makefile for ability to build modules one at a time. There are builds for just about everything out there already, so maybe consider a prebuilt (and pre-patched) version as well?